# Elasticsearch fuzzy querying without request

Tags: python, elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch I am capable of finding the results of a query (in this case "Science") with following code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'localhost','port':9200}])

from elasticsearch_dsl import Search    

s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("match", text="Science")
```

But let's say I type "Sci3nce" then I get not results back.

How can I do fuzzy querying without using request, but using the elasticsearch library of python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`fuzzy` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html):

```
s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("fuzzy", text={"query": "Sci3nce", "fuzziness": 2})
```

Comment: What if we have two typo's? Like: `text="Sci3nc3"`?

Comment: You can play with the [`fuzziness`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness)  parameter

Comment: Is this still possible with something similar to `s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("fuzzy", text="Sci3nce")` (without using requests the tutorial that you are showing is using requests type of call)

Comment: with `s = Search(using=es, index="my_name").query("fuzzy", text={"query": "Sci3nce", "fuzziness": 2})` I get the error: **elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[fuzzy] query does not support [query]')**

Comment: @jenniferruurs since this question is closed, do you mind creating a new one referencing this one and which describes your new issue?